# vb.net Selenium Webdriver findelement

Tags: vb.net, svg, selenium-webdriver

Please understand that i'm not good at english.
There is a page that contains many rect in svg
I upload this page's html source .
There is a rect like this

```
<rect x="1720.68" y="726.97" width="11" height="11" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#bca888" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect>
```

and There is a rect like that

```
<rect x="1707.36" y="646.85" width="11" height="11" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#dddddd" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect>
```

**But** These rects are in svg

```
<svg height="526" version="1.1" width="682" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="1478.4759521484375 577.7315063476562 317.18333435058594 197.59629821777344" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);">
```

I want to program that click rect filled with **"#baa882 color"**
I tried to findelement by CssSelector, but it's too slow to use.
(I wanna fast program that Find Element immediately.)
Moreover, There is no way to work findelement by id or tagname.
*(Please let me know if there is any available method.)*

How can I make a program on condition?

Comment: post your relevant code...

Comment: I don't think so it is safe for anyone to download .zip from a random url posted by a stranger. Can you please put the html in the question itself.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The text has been modified.